# Phonegap turn on/off light screen

Tags: cordova, screen

I am working in a phonegap project for android handling some notifications. I need to control the light of the screen to turn on the screen when an event occurs (arrives a notification) or to turn off the screen after a while of inactivity.

I have tried some phonegap plugins like insomnia, keepscreenon and what these plugins do is to keep the light of the screen on.

PLease your help...

Answer (score 0):

Using the [ScreenDim](https://github.com/alunny/ScreenDim) you can turn off and on the screen light. Here the some code example of it.

```
document.getElementById('turnoff').addEventListener('touchstart', function (e) {
        cordova.screenDim.disable();
    });

    // turn it back on
    document.getElementById('turnon').addEventListener('touchstart', function (e) {
        cordova.screenDim.enable();
    });

    // toggle it
    document.getElementById('toggle').addEventListener('touchstart', function (e) {
        cordova.screenDim.toggle();
    });
```

Comment: Is this still working? There were 2 less promising issue reports when I checked. Did not try it yet.

Comment: I am not sure about it. because I had tried it 4 years ago.